# NodeJS - nodemailer using nodemailer-smtp-transport

Tags: node.js, email, ssl, nodemailer

I'm having an issue getting nodemailer to work with AuthSMTP (https://www.authsmtp.com/).

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transOptions = {
    host: 'mail.authsmtp.com',
    port: 25,
    secure: false,
    auth: {
        user: '...',
        pass: '...'
    }
};
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(transOptions);
var mainOptions = {
    from: 'whatever@domain.com',
    to: 'something@domain.com',
    subject: 'hello',
    text: 'hello world!'
};
var callback = function(err, info){
    if (err) { throw err }
    console.log('sent');
}
transporter.sendMail(mainOptions, callback);
```

The error I'm getting back from AuthSMTP is:

> "Your program, application or device is trying to use SSL with our
>   service but SSL is not enabled on your account."

I don't want to enable SSL, and I have the `secure` property in the transport options object set to `false` as the docs say: https://github.com/andris9/nodemailer-smtp-transport#usage.

Why would AuthSMTP say I'm using SSL when I'm setting `nodemailer` not to use SSL...?

Comment: can you check whether authsmtp control panel has SSL on ! by default it should be off

Comment: It's off in the control panel, hence the error message above saying it's not enabled...

Comment: Better you use supported services by node mailer, I am using same with Zoho mail as SMTP and works like charm. list here https://github.com/andris9/nodemailer-wellknown#supported-services

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you may try this

```
var transOptions = {
host: 'mail.authsmtp.com',
port: 25,
secure: false,
ignoreTLS: true
auth: {
    user: '...',
    pass: '...',

}
```

Comment: They address this issue, here https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer/commit/1995f46d7266c162c3c6b6d30767c96d962b32d4

Comment: It's working now, you were almost there... It was `ignoreTLS: true` in the options object (not under the `auth` object). If you update your answer I'll accept it. Cheers!

Comment: Done , Thanks. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

> secure – if true the connection will use TLS when connecting to
>   server. If false (the default) then TLS is used if server supports the
>   STARTTLS extension.

In most cases set this value to true if you are connecting to port 465. For port 587 or 25 keep it false.

> ignoreTLS – if this is true and secure is false then TLS is not used
>   even if the server supports STARTTLS extension.

so, params like this:

> secure: false,   ignoreTLS: true,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be safe, I think just to set you email, start IMAP/SMTP and POP/SMTP service as below:

[image]

and add your pass on your email settings:

[image]